# How to change culture to a DateTimepicker or calendar control in .Net

Tags: c#, .net, internationalization, datetimepicker, culture

How to set internationalization to a `DateTimepicker` or `Calendar WinForm` control in .Net when the desire culture is different to the one installed in the PC?

Comment: Today I ran into same problem. It appears that it is not possible. I need custom time format hh:mm in 23:59 format, but no matter what I try (Culture, UICulture, etc.) it always shows 11:59.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It doesn't seem to be possible to change the culture. See this [KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/Default.aspx?scid=kb%3ben-us%3b889834&x=18&y=19).

Comment: Link to KB article is dead... :( They should've fixed it by now... it's 8 years later...

Comment: Both these links are down now

Comment: KB article from the webarchive   https://web.archive.org/web/20110718101517/http://support.microsoft.com/kb/889834

Answer (score 5):

Based on previous solution, I think the better is:

```
dateTimePicker.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
dateTimePicker.CustomFormat = Application.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern;
```

Comment: Returns "dd-MMM-yy" for me, how does that help to change the culture?

Answer (score 0):

For DateTimePicker

```
dtp.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
dtp.CustomFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"; // or the format you prefer
```

Comment: Setting the format is not the only thing controlled by the culture.  It controls a lot of other things, such as whether the first day of the week is Sunday or Monday.

Comment: Format is used only to show current date, but if you want to choose it, datetimepicker control will show full date, based on the regional settings.

Answer (score 0):

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("fr");
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
```

Comment: That will not change the regional settings of the Windows, only the current UI culture and current culture of the current thread (as the properties' names suggest). But DateTimePicker control looks only for the regional setting of the Windows, so it doesn't matter.

Answer (score -1):

I think there is detour.

1. set event handler "ValueChanged"
2. code

   ```
   dateTimePicker.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
   string[] formats = dateTimePicker.Value.GetDateTimeFormats(Application.CurrentCulture);
   dateTimePicker.CustomFormat = formats[0];
   ```

Comment: GetDateTimeFormats() does not produce format strings (that can be used to do formatting), but formatted strings (the result of formatting). Assigning such a string to .CustomFormat makes no sense. Would vote down answer, but lacking reputation myself...

Answer (score -1):

Use the telerik radDateTimePicker and write this code , after InitializeComponent(), and Instead of "fa-IR" use your culture.

```
Application.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("fa-IR"); 
radDateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
radDateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = Application.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern;
```