# How to change locale for the calendar?

Tags: winapi, calendar, locale

ALL,
I've been searching MSDN for the last couple of days and even asked on codeguru but to no availability.
So here goes...

Let's say I have a Windows XP computer whose current locale set to US-en. The calendar at the bottom right corner displays the date as 2/14/2014.
Now, let's say I am developing a program and I need to call the DatePicker control to show the date. And let's say that the user of the program will be around the world. For the sake of simplicity I will pick my own country - Russia. ;-)
Now how do I change the locale to the Russian? I thought I could just use ::SetThreadLocale() and be done, but this function will affect only some resources of my program, namely the dialog titles will be one. But it does not affect the calendar nor the DatePicker control.
Searching MSDN I found 2 more functions: SetLocaleInfo() which can't be called as MSDN says it will affect every single application on the system - not what I want - my only, and SetCalendarInfo() which looks OK, but I'm not sure if this is the one.

So, did I find the right function to call and if not is there a way to do what I want?

Thank you.

Comment: Hi there, what programming language (framework) are you using ? If VS then you might take a look at [`this question`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/241964/960757).

Comment: Yes, Visual Studio C/C++. And apparently it is not possible - meaning the control is not locale-aware. :(