# DateTimePicker giving Exception with custom format

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, datetimepicker

I'm receiving the following exception when I try to use a custom format in my `DateTimePicker` :

"The string was not recognized as a valid DateTime."

I'm using the following snippet :

```
  dtpSystemAdjustmentDate.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
  dtpSystemAdjustmentDate.CustomFormat = "mm.dd.yyyy hh:mm:ss";
```

I've found documentation on the Microsoft help pages : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983603%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

I Tried this snippet :

```
    // C#
    dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "'Today is:' hh:mm:ss dddd MMMM dd, yyyy";
```

I'm receiving also an exception, complaining about "Today" being a keyword that is not recognized.

I suspect something related to culture (my current Culture is `fr-CH`) but I can't find a way to make it work... Any idea ?

Comment: On which line you get this _string was not recognized_ exception? Can you please show all code? And what is your `CurrentCulture`?

Comment: Any help by reading this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/241964/how-to-change-culture-to-a-datetimepicker-or-calendar-control-in-net ?

Comment: I'm not receiving the exception when starting my application with break points on those lines...

Comment: My currentCulture is fr-CH.

Comment: Commenting the first two code lines of my question removes the exception... So the exception should be around there... I also tried to invert the lines to put the CustomFormat first... Doesn't change the behavior...

Comment: I've found my problem. We're inheriting one of our Form classes that is in charge of translating all the controls in the form. Unfortunately, it handles pretty badly the translation of DateTimePicker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem wasn't related to .Net or C#.

I tried a blank project, using the same code and it worked.

I was inheriting a subclass of `Form` that is in charge of translating the `Controls` within the form. Unfortunately, something is messing up the text content of my `DateTimePicker`.

My previous lines were correct.